# Imagemagick montage, different -extent values for 3 images

Tags: imagemagick

I have the following ImageMagick code that makes a poster out of 3 images, and it works well, however I would like to have a different `-extent` value for each of the 3 images. How would I do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
exec("montage -background black $img_1 $img_2 $img_3 -geometry 390x620+5+5 -gravity center -extent 396x626^ $img_out");
```

Comment: What are the image dimensions & how is it supposed to look when done correctly?

Comment: Hi Mark. I would like the -extent value to be dynamic depending on n number of variables. So rather than have -extent 396x626 applied to all 3 images, I'd like to have each image have its own -extent values. The current project can be seen here http://cozomo.com/test_dev/montage.php?img1=d2e299ecd91.jpg&img2=c9cf589e4f3.jpg&img3=c1e193c063b.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but I think the following might help you get where you are trying to go - hopefully!

I would tend to use `convert` rather than `montage`, so let's create three different size images, red, green and blue

```
convert -size 120x200 xc:red red.png
convert -size 200x300 xc:lime green.png
convert -size 80x120 xc:blue blue.png
```

they look like this

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now I try and make a poster, using a different shade of grey background for each "*picture*" and a different size and hope you can adapt that to your needs:

```
convert -gravity center \
   \( -background gray70 red.png   -extent 800x300 \)   \
   \( -background gray40 green.png -extent 300x300 \)   \
   \( -background gray10 blue.png  -extent 100x300 \)   \ 
   +append result.png
```

[image]